# Dijkstra's Single Source Shourtest Path with an extra edge with weight of 'w'

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

In an recent interview I was asked to implement single source shortest path algorithm(for undirected and positive weighted graph) with slight modification i.e. we're given an extra edge with weight 'w'. And we have to find if we can find a more shorter path, than the one calculated by SSSP algo, by connecting that extra edge, with weight 'w', between two nodes which are not already connected.
[Here's an image. As according to SSSP the shortest path between A(source) & D(destination)is A-B-C-D i.e. total of 8.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amkHH.jpg)

But given the extra edge. It can be connected between A and D, which are not already connected, to minimize the shortest path yielded through SSSP algo.
[Image of graph with extra edge contributing the shortest path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18rwE.jpg)

I tried thinking about the solution. But nothing struck so far. I've implemented the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path. But this little modification has baffled me. So can you help a little bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options:

1. We don't need an extra edge. This case is handled by a standard Dijkstra algorithm.
2. A shortest path with an extra edge looks like this: `shortest_path(start, V) + (V, U) + shortest_path(U, target)`. That is, we go from the start to some vertex `V` by the shortest path in the original graph, then we go to `U` (again, an arbitrary vertex) by adding this extra edge (`V` and `U` mustn't be connected) and then we go from `U` to the target node by the shortest path in the original graph.
3. We can use the structure of the path to get an `O(n ^ 2)` solution: we can compute shortest paths from the start node to all the others (one run of the Dijkstra's algorithm) and all shortest paths from the target node to all other nodes (one more run). Now we can just iterate over all possible pairs `(V, U)` and pick the best one.
4. Bonus: we can solve it in `O(m log n)` for a sparse graph. The idea is as follows: instead of checking all `(U, V)` pairs, we can find such `U` that it has the minimal distance to the target among all vertices that are not connected to `V` in `degree(V) * log V` (or even linear) time (this problem is known as finding the smallest element not in the set).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure I ubderstand your question. You Have a weighted graph ,and can add a edge with w, add to where make shortest path.
I think we can use spfa + dp to solve the problem. Set all other edge to w and create boolean matrix m, m[i,j] =1 mean no edge between i,j, dp[u,0] mean shortest distance when we reach u without using an extra edge, dp[u,1]mean using an  extra edge. I don’t write the dp transfer equation. So we can iterate in spfa,  and we can also backtrack the best way of dp and get where to set an extra edge.

We do not use Dijkstra algorithm in above solution.

spfa is also a Single Source Shourtest Path algoritm, it can deal negative weighted edge, but not negative cycle.

It’s just my think,i have not try it.but I think it’s a idea to solve it.
If any wrong, tell me please.