# Get shortest path with an extra edge with weight 'w'?

Tags: python, shortest-path, dijkstra, graph-traversal

The question is like [Dijkstra's Single Source Shourtest Path with an extra edge with weight of 'w'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089933/dijkstras-single-source-shourtest-path-with-an-extra-edge-with-weight-of-w).

You are given an undirected weighted graph, which is represented as an adjacency matrix. Find the shortest path between a start node and a finish node in the graph. You are allowed to add at most one edge of a given weight between any two nodes that are not directly connected to each other.

Example:

For `start = 1`, `finish = 4`, `weight = 2` and

```
graph = [[0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
         [2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 3, 0],
         [4, 0, 3, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

the output should be
`shortestPathWithEdge(start, finish, weight, graph) == 3`.

My current solution uses Dijstra, but i run it multiple times base on how many possible edges there are. I know with Dijstra, you can get the shortest path to all the nodes, but I cant seem to think of a way to manipulate that data by adding an edge connection without running Dijstra algorithm over again.

The graph can be 1000x1000.  So with a large matrix, my solution will be too slow and will not work.

Is there a quick update that can be done to Dijstra algorithm to handle additional edges?

My code is below, it works but quite slow.  Maybe `copy.copy` is also causing it to be a lot slower than it should.

```
import copy

def getDistances(graph):
    ##### GET DISTANCES FROM GRAPH
    ##### PLACE IN DICTIONARY FORM
    distances = {}
    edges = set()

    for i, node in enumerate(graph):
        distances[i+1] = {}
        for j, distance in enumerate(node):
            ##### NO NEED TO GET DISTANCE TO ITSELF
            if i != j:
                distances[i+1][j+1] = distance
                if distance == 0 and (i+1,j+1) not in edges and (j+1,i+1) not in edges:
                    ##### ADD TO EDGES
                    edges.add((i+1,j+1))

    return distances, edges

def dijstra(visited,unvisited,currentNode,currentDistance,distances,finish):
    while True:
        for neighbor, distance in distances[currentNode].items():
            if distance == 0 or neighbor not in unvisited:
                continue

            newDistance = currentDistance + distance
            if unvisited[neighbor] == None or unvisited[neighbor] > newDistance:
                unvisited[neighbor] = newDistance

        visited[currentNode] = currentDistance
        del unvisited[currentNode]

        if not unvisited:
            break

        candidates = [node for node in unvisited.items() if node[1]]
        currentNode, currentDistance = sorted(candidates, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

    ##### VISITED CONTAINS SHORTEST PATH TO ALL NODES
    return visited[finish]

def shortestPathWithEdge(start, finish, weight, graph):

    best = 10000000

    nodes = { i+1 for i in range(len(graph)) }
    distances, edges = getDistances(graph)

    #####IF NO EXTRA EDGE
    # visited = {}
    # unvisited = { node:None for node in nodes}
    # currentNode = start
    # currentDistance = 0
    # solution = dijstra(visited,unvisited,currentNode,currentDistance,distances,finish)

    #####WITH AN EXTRA EDGE
    solution = 10000000
    for node1, node2 in edges:
        _distances = copy.copy(distances)
        _distances[node1][node2] = weight
        visited = {}
        unvisited = {node: None for node in nodes}
        currentNode = start
        currentDistance = 0
        shortest2 = dijstra(visited, unvisited, currentNode, currentDistance, _distances, finish)

        solution = min(solution,shortest2)

    return solution


start = 1
finish = 4
weight = 2

graph = [[0, 2, 0, 4, 0],\
            [2, 0, 1, 0, 0], \
            [0, 1, 0, 3, 0], \
            [4, 0, 3, 0, 1],\
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

print("Answer:", shortestPathWithEdge(start, finish, weight, graph))
```

Comment: When working with matrices, using `numpy` usually speeds up things.

Comment: Regarding your question about `copy`, you could profile your code and answer that conclusively.